# In what year is The Beach set?

Tags: the-beach

In The Beach (2000), a lost Leonardo DiCaprio classic, couple of young adults swim to a paradise island for adventure.

I tried to figure out what year the plot is set. The movie was released in 2000 and throughout the movie you can hear various electronic dance music songs from the mid to late 90s.

Was the plot set in 90s? Has anyone read the book, does it mention the year?

Anyway, I assume it's set in the 90s, because at the beginning you can see The Simpsons scene running in the back and The Simpsons came out in late 80s.

So maybe late 80s/90s?

Comment: Since the novel was published in 1996 and the movie came out in 2000 we can safely assume it's set in the early/mid-90s

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any script that I can find does not mention any dates.  In the absence of anything that I can find about the movie (and I don't have access to a copy) the only thing I can find is from the [wikipedia page about the novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beach_(novel)) which states:

> When Richard, Étienne, and Françoise arrive, it is already 1995

Some of the music is from the mid 90's period, but some is later, e.g. Pure Shores by All Saints is from 2000 the year of the movie release.  However this might be non-diegetic (not music heard by the characters).

In the absence of other information I think its fair to say that the source material dates it to 1995.